# PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 320x240 only on headless RPI startup

Tags: opencv, flask, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I have a program where I start a flask server and stream video using PiCameraStream(). Whenever I start this as a daemon program directly or with python3 stream/main.py connected to a monitor I have no issues. However, when this program starts streaming headless not connected to any monitors I get the buffer length error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set a default screen resolution as follows to cover the case when it can't be obtained from your monitor:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then choose:

```
2) Display Options -> D1 Resolution -> Default.
```